# How iOS handles events that occurs just right before the background?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-background-mode, ios-lifecycle

First of all I'd like to say sorry in case my question is dummy, I'm really new to iOS and what to understand how thing are going on. Imagine such a situation - user taps on home button and the app starts to collapse, but immediately after taping on home button user taped on some UI element. So, I'm wondering how the iOS will handle this? I tried to do some tests using breakpoints, but since it just test I can't be 100% sure. It seems that if the UI interaction event will happen before the system will call `willResignActive` then the event will be fully processed and if the system will call `willResignActive` first, then the even will be discarded and won't be handled at all. Is this correct, or I missed something? Thanks

Comment: On iPhone's without a home button as soon as you drag up from the bottom of the screen (even the smallest amount), then willResignActive is called, and UI events are immediately ignored.  What situation are you trying to handle?

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you want to use this in your app? If a user presses a button exactly in this time, it's okay that the action is not handled.

The only thing you have to keep track of is that whenever the button gets pressed and let's say you store a file without a completion handler it could be that you present an alert which is saying that everything went well but you actually not saved the file because the user left the app in this time.

But since you're never doing critical actions without completion handlers, in my opinion, there's no need to make sure that this doesn't happen.

If I got you wrong, just comment!